# Android Hierarchy viewer is missing

Tags: android, android-layout

Hierarchy Viewer tool is missing from my android-sdk-windows\tools directory.

Link to tool:
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html

Should it be there is first place?

P.S. SDK Tools rev. 7, Platforms 7 & 8 packages are installed.

Comment: It is correctly installed here (Ubuntu Linux 10.04, Eclipse 3.5). Do you have any additional information?

Comment: Not much... I've downloaded SDK yesterday, only new ones (7 and 8) maybe it resides in older version?

Comment: [How can I  Use Hierarchy Viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45055690/6521116)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a problem with the Windows SDK tools distribution. [This](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/sdk.git;a=blob;f=hierarchyviewer/etc/hierarchyviewer1.bat;h=3f8c41628327e73eb276eb128bef77c75c7892fd;hb=HEAD) might be the right version from the open source project. Otherwise, perhaps somebody else who is presently running Windows can publish a link to it.

Comment: Then, what one should do with it if he doesn't have the app itself? :)

Comment: "The app itself" is a JAR that, AFAIK, should still have been distributed.

Answer (score 0):

In my windows install, there is a hierarchyviewer.jar in `\tools\lib` directory.
Open a command prompt in that directory, type "hierarchyviewer.jar" and press enter.
That starts the hierarchyviewer for me at least.